# Maven release and recomposed POM family

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm having some issues running the Maven release plugin in my company's specific maven structure. Let me explain the concept of recomposed family I'm referring to. My projects are multimodule projects, where each module may have a different parent than its natural father.

```
project/
    pom.xml (the natural multimodule reactor father) (I list as modules all that follows)
    module1/pom.xml (my parent is NOT ../pom.xml, I'm a half sibling)
    module2/pom.xml (my parent is ../pom.xml, I'm a natural child) (I have a dependency on module1)
    project-war/pom.xml (my parent is NOT ../pom.xml, I'm a half sibling)
```

The reason we adopt this "foster parent" strategy, is that we want to activate some plugins by default for some specific "adopted siblings". For example, every WAR projects needs to define a specific maven-resource-plugin execution ID. Since we have about 80 WARs to generate, imagine the maintenance if we are to add an extra execution step to ALL WARs. This works well for development purposes, we do have valid and running SNAPSHOTs building and deploying.

Now that we want to release, the maven-release-plugin seems not to like this specific structure. In short, since module2 needs module1, but module1 has a different father, release plugin keeps module1 as a SNAPSHOT.

My question here is, has anyone manage to release a projects with recomposed family members? Is there any configuration that I need in the release plugin to enable a full release of such projects?

Answer (score 2):

Violating the inheritance between modules are parent is going to give you more problems than anything else.

Your only options here are either:

- fix the parent-children model so the release plugin can do its job (and then move those module activations to the children where you want it)
- do the tagging, changing of versions, build+release (mvn deploy , and optionally also site-deploy) manually

Answer (score 0):

After some further tests, here are my conclusions about this issue.

The recomposed family CAN be tackled by Maven on a simple condition: ALL members of the family are present in the reactor.

That would mean having a "super-reactor" that has a reference to both the project you want to release, and the parent poms that may be declared by some modules. Of course, the release plugin will then release everything in this super reactor. If you have many projects that all refer the same parent projects, you should release them in one shot.

Moreover, for the build model to be generated correctly, all relative paths must be right. In my specific case, we wanted to avoid such a thing, I guess we are back to setting a fixed folder structure.

It could be handy to exclude some projects from the release plugin, but of course that creates a potential instability.